# ViewController loading twice xcode iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I know what causes it to load twice, but I do not know how to fix the problem. I have looked through many other questions at the same topic, but any of those are matching to my problem.

So here's the code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
        super.performSegueWithIdentifier("TVtoVCSegue", sender: selectedCell)
        print("kolm")
    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "TVtoVCSegue" {
            let otherViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TTDetailCntr

            if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell, text = cell.textLabel?.text {
                otherViewController.CurrentClass = text
            }
        }
    }
```

As I understand, in tableview function

```
super.performSegueWithIdentifier("TVtoVCSegue", sender: selectedCell)
```

Calls out the view to load and the function below itself calls out the view to load,

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
```

both will load the view so I tried to integrate those methods and  I tried to do sth like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow! as NSIndexPath
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

    super.performSegueWithIdentifier("TVtoVCSegue", sender: selectedCell)

    if segue.identifier == "TVtoVCSegue" {
        let otherViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TTDetailCntr

        if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell, text = cell.textLabel?.text {
            otherViewController.CurrentClass = text
        }
    }
}
```

But It says an error if I try to access the view that loaded twice before:
The error comes from the line:

```
super.performSegueWithIdentifier("TVtoVCSegue", sender: selectedCell)
```

And the error is:

```
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
(lldb)
```

The idea of the code is to get the indexPath value and then pass it to another ViewController

Comment: write `self.performSeque` and check instead of super

Comment: Did you assign class for the second view controller ?

Comment: Yes I did and I put the code here as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

The **segue** that you've created is most probably from a **tableViewCell** rather than the **UIViewController**

Delete the segue and create one from the **UIViewController** instead.

[image: drag and drop from highlisghted part]

Ctrl + drag from the circle highlighted in the image to your destination VC.

This will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

write

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier
```

and check instead of

```
super.performSegueWithIdentifier
```

Its working fine with this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){     
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("TVtoVCSegue", sender: selectedCell)
    print("kolm")
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "TVtoVCSegue" {
        let otherViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController

        if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {
            otherViewController.CurrentClass = cell.textLabel?.text
        }
    }

}
```

**SecondControllerClass.swift**

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var CurrentClass:String!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: At the same line: 'self.performSegueWithIdentifier("TVtoVCSegue", sender: selectedCell)'

Comment: @KarlKivi which version of Swift u r using?

Comment: your code is working fine with swift 2.1, I just made a sample

Comment: have u assinged Current class as a String in new controller

Comment: This code works, but still the secondview is loaded twice! Is there any method that I can implement to stop the view to load more than once? @Rajan

Comment: Yes, we can easily push or present controller without using segue. But still, lets also figure out why this is happening

Comment: @KarlKivi Can you recheck the code as in my case the view is loaded only once by using the above code.

Comment: Well, I got rid of the problem by changing the Storyboard segue kind from "Show" to "present modally" programm works now perfectly as I want it to work, but it says an error in debug area that really isnt causing my project to stop working or anything, so Should I ignore the error or somehow fix it? Error says:  Attempt to present <Poska_App.SecondViewController: 0x13f5dbcb0> on <Poska_App.FirstViewController: 0x13f635e30> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SecondviewController that receives the passed data:

```
class TTDetailCntr: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var ClassIDLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var TeacherIDlbl: UILabel!

    var CurrentClass = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ClassIDLbl.text = CurrentClass

    }
```